# Django aggregation does excessive GROUP BY clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, django, aggregation

I am doing a very simple aggregation using the Django ORM on MySQL, and it is producing a `GROUP BY` clause that includes the `data` field, which is very large, and is slowing down the query by over 100-fold.

Here is a simplified version of the model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()

class Attachment(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
```

And the query I am running:

```
Document.objects.annotate(num_attachments=Count('attachment'))
```

And the SQL output:

```
SELECT
  `document_document`.`id`,
  `document_document`.`data`,
  COUNT(`document_attachment`.`id`) AS `num_attachments`
FROM `document_document`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `document_attachment`
    ON (`document_document`.`id` = `document_attachment`.`document_id`) 
GROUP BY
  `document_document`.`id`,
  `document_document`.`id`,
  `document_document`.`data`
ORDER BY NULL
```

Doing `GROUP BY` on the data field is unnecessary and ridiculous. I can stop this by doing a `values` query:

```
Document.objects.values('pk').annotate(num_attachments=Count('attachment'))
```

But then how do I get a real, annotated Document query as the result?

Comment: That is strange, I tried a similar example with a Foreign Key and it wouldn't work. I could only get it to work with a ManyToMany relationship. I know this is a simplified version of the models, do you possibly have a different ManyToManyField pointing to the Document somewhere? Or is there a Document self field, a Document referencing another Document?

Comment: I set up the same models and tried, only I added a `name = models.CharField(max_length=24)` and got something similar, only it had a GROUP BY for all three fields, TWICE! Definitely seems like a bug. I am using version 1.3.1 with the same results.

Comment: @Furbeenator I couldn't find anything related on the Django bug tracker. I'm on 1.3.0 by the way.

Comment: Very nice, I saw you opened a bug ticket and are going to work on a patch. It looks like they are looping the fields creating a GROUP BY for each field in the loop, possibly an embedded loop is why I got it twice for each of the three fields in my example. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Karen Tracy, a Django core committer, has confirmed that this is actually a bug in Django:

http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/22d4d46c8646b2c4#

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17144

Comment: For anyone who bumps into this question again, this issue is fixed in Django 1.6 and later. See the git diff https://github.com/django/django/commit/cafb266954e21dd55ddfa90597bcf02c022bcb7d